# Pandas Grouped and sum data column that separated by special character

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset contain price , date and cost type .
Column "cost type" element seperted by ‘-‘ character .
I want to sum of element and grouped in A1,A2,A3 ... category .
I see some of question and answer in stackoverflow in pandas but all of them solve
a special problem

**Orginal** datafram same below :

```
 price          date      cost type
+ 14,000    1399/03/02   A11 - A1 -A
+ 5,500     1399/02/25   A31 - A3 -A
+ 67,500    1399/02/22   A21 - A2 -A
+ 10,000    1399/02/20   A11 - A1 -A
+ 8,000     1399/02/19   A12 - A1 -A
+ 5,000     1399/02/19   A31 - A3 -A
+ 8,000     1399/02/15   A12 - A1 -A
+ 5,000     1399/02/12   A32 - A3 -A
+ 14,000    1399/02/10   A13 - A1 -A
+ 5,000     1399/02/09   A31 - A3 -A
+ 2,000     1399/02/08   A33 - A3 -A
+ 27,200    1399/02/03   A11 - A1 -A
+ 66,500    1399/01/31   A21 - A2 -A
+ 10,000    1399/01/20   A11 - A1 -A
+ 10,000    1399/01/18   A12 - A1 -A
+ 10,000    1399/01/18   A11 - A1 -A
+ 8,000     1399/01/06   A12 - A1 -A
+ 9,000     1399/01/04   A11 - A1 -A
+ 20,000    1398/12/28   A14 - A1 -A
```

I want to sum and grouped
**Result** dataframe same bellow :

```
CostType(Main )    CostType(Branch )                    Cost
      A                  A1            Sum of all element ( A11 , A12 , A13 , … ) 
                         A2            Sum of all element ( A21 , A22 , A23 , … ) 
                         A3            Sum of all element ( A31 , A32 , A33 , … )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the column which you want to split with `str.split()`. Then, join it to the original data frame. Group them together and sum them up.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
price date "cost type"
14,000 1399/03/02 "A11 - A1 -A"
5,500 1399/02/25 "A31 - A3 -A"
67,500 1399/02/22 "A21 - A2 -A"
10,000 1399/02/20 "A11 - A1 -A"
8,000 1399/02/19 "A12 - A1 -A"
5,000 1399/02/19 "A31 - A3 -A"
8,000 1399/02/15 "A12 - A1 -A"
5,000 1399/02/12 "A32 - A3 -A"
14,000 1399/02/10 "A13 - A1 -A"
5,000 1399/02/09 "A31 - A3 -A"
2,000 1399/02/08 "A33 - A3 -A"
27,200 1399/02/03 "A11 - A1 -A"
66,500 1399/01/31 "A21 - A2 -A"
10,000 1399/01/20 "A11 - A1 -A"
10,000 1399/01/18  "A12 - A1 -A"
10,000 1399/01/18 "A11 - A1 -A"
8,000 1399/01/06 "A12 - A1 -A"
9,000 1399/01/04 "A11 - A1 -A"
20,000 1398/12/28 "A14 - A1 -A"
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

df['price'] = df['price'].str.replace(',','').astype(int)
df2 = pd.concat([df[['price','date']], df['cost type'].str.split('-', expand=True)], axis=1)
df2.rename(columns={0:'type_c',1:'type_b',2:'type_a'}, inplace=True)
df2.groupby(['type_a','type_b'])['price'].sum().reset_index()

    type_a  type_b  price
0   A   A1  148200
1   A   A2  134000
2   A   A3  22500
```

Comment: I use only first command for remove `,` but I get ERROER `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I added the code from the point of importing the data you presented.
Is the layout of the data the same? Please check.

Comment: I read data from excel CSV file . I delete `,` then I want to delete `+` I see `,` come back! I don't know how can I remove all `,` and `+` together . I don't want change my excel file same your data , I want to import it by `read_csv(filename)` and do my operation

Comment: A useful feature called `pd.read_excel()` is provided to read an Excel file directly into You can try the reading process.